# Displaying string in realtime using curses

Tags: python

I have a string that when printed is 300 lines long. My first thought was to use curses to display the string. But the string is constantly changing and I also want the user to be able to scroll through each of the lines.

As an example I hav ethe following code...

```
from itertools import cycle
import curses, contextlib, time

@contextlib.contextmanager
def curses_screen():
    """Contextmanager's version of curses.wrapper()."""
    try:
        stdscr=curses.initscr()
        curses.noecho()
        curses.cbreak()
        stdscr.keypad(1)
        try: curses.start_color()
        except: pass

        yield stdscr
    finally:
        stdscr.keypad(0)
        curses.echo()
        curses.nocbreak()
        curses.endwin()

with curses_screen() as stdscr:
    pad = curses.newpad(100, 100)
    pad.addstr(0,0, curses.longname())
    for i in range(1, 90):
        pad.addstr(i,0, str(i))

    coord = 5, 5, 10, 75
    pad.refresh(0, 0, *coord)

    KEY_UP, KEY_DOWN = 'AB'
    y = 0
    for c in iter(pad.getkey, 'q'):
        if c in '\x1b\x5b': continue # skip escape seq
        y -= (c == KEY_UP)
        y += (c == KEY_DOWN)
        y = min(max(y, 0), 10)
        pad.refresh(y, 0, *coord)
```

However if the strings in this case needed to be displayed as

```
for i in range(11, 99):
    print i
```

How would I update the pad ?

Comment: Can you show some piece of code?

Comment: tried to add some more detail/code to the question

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is that you update the pad with the new text just like you did with the original text:

```
pad.erase()
for (py, i) in enumerate(range(1, 90), 1):
     pad.addstr(py, 0, str(i))
pad.refresh(y, 0, *coord)
```

Comment: I tried to add this to the code but I was unable to get this to work. Can you confirm how this would look in the original code.

Comment: It depends on when you want to change what gets displayed. In your example code it would obviously have to go inside the loop where you check the keyboard, since that's where it spends all of its time. IF that doesn't do what you want than it appears your real question isn't how to update the pad with a new set of strings. If the new set of strings isn't generated as a result of the user's key presses then you'll need to explain exactly under what conditions the new text is generated.